# SPO Person or Group users pickers field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, person-or-group

I have a field of type **Person or Group** in the list, different users will access this list, i don't want the other users pick another users from the drop down to create for them requests.

In this field i just want to show their current email when they type their name, so he can only pick his/her name.

For example in this field my name is not **Sandeep** and i am logging in other account so i type the name of Sandeep it shows me to pick him while it should not.

[image]

Any idea how can i achieve it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know all your requirements. But, I think if users are going to add the requests and you don't want them to select another user's name then you can leverage the OOTB "Created By" column.

Comment: Or you can customize the list form using PowerApps. Make the field disabled and set default value to current user creating the request.

Comment: My requirements is that the field should not show other users, just his own email so he can't search for me or any others.@Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Then you can customize the form in powerapps to auto-populate the current users email instead of giving user an option to search for his email or other users email.

Comment: If PowerApps is the best solution can you please show me how to do it ?@Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Check the working solution given [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Auto-populate-person-type-column-with-logged-in-user/m-p/144169) or [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Set-current-user-as-default-value-of-Person-or-Group-field/td-p/78744). You need to leverage `User()` function in PowerApps.

Comment: You can find another detailed article at [Set Current User As Default Value Of Person/ Group Field In PowerApps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-current-user-as-default-value-of-person-group-field-in-powerapps/).

Comment: I will check them out and let you know. Thank you @GaneshSanap

Comment: I followed one of these tutorials and i get the right results in PowerApps. So the users right now will use PowerApps to create their requests instead of SharePoint ?Because when i get back to the list i still can search for other users.@GaneshSanap

Comment: You need to make the field disable in your form by setting `Disabled` property of that particular field in PowerApps

Comment: Yes, i did it works in PowerApps. But in SharePoint it keeps showing the users here take a look here: https://i.imgur.com/nXg8DRz.png @GaneshSanap

Comment: Is this the list form?? User should not be able to edit the person or group field if you have disabled it from PowerApps.

Comment: Yes it's a list, so i will use Created By column instead of using PowerApps.@GaneshSanap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all your requirements.

But, I think if users are going to add the requests and you don't want them to select another user's name then you can leverage the OOTB **Created By** column.

**Another approach**:

Or you can customize the list form using PowerApps. Make the field `Disabled` and set `Default` value of person or group field to current user creating the request. You need to leverage `User()` function in PowerApps.

**References**:

1. [Set Current User As Default Value Of Person/ Group Field In PowerApps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-current-user-as-default-value-of-person-group-field-in-powerapps/)
2. [Set current user as default value of Person or Group field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Set-current-user-as-default-value-of-Person-or-Group-field/td-p/78744).